# Google Webmaster Tools Not Reporting a Logo from JSON-LD Schema.org [Organization] Markup

Tags: google-search-console

I have been waiting for 6+ months for Google Webmaster Tools to report that is has found the logo which is nested our Organization markup. I see no syntax error and the testing tool reports is Good to go. Not sure why it is not able to pull it. Here is the snippet with HTTPS and CaSe sensitive src we use:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "Organization",
"name" : "A Giant Corporation",
"url" : "https://www.example.com",
"logo" : "https://www.example.com/image/data/SampleLogoWithCaps-2015-01-15-BLACK.png",
"founder" : "A Dude",
"foundingDate" : "1648",
"sameAs" : "http://plus.google.com/21324354324324",
"contactPoint" : {
    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "contactType" : "Customer Service",
    "telephone" : "+1-888-888-8888",
    "faxNumber" : "+1-555-555-5555",
    "contactOption" : "TollFree",
    "areaServed" : "US",
    "availableLanguage" : "English",
    "email" : "support@example.com"
},
"hasPos" : {
    "@type" : "Place",
    "name" : "An Arm or Store",
    "photo" : "https://www.example.com/image/data/this-store-photo.png",
    "hasMap" : {
        "@type" : "Map",
        "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "address" : {
        "@type" : "PostalAddress",
        "name" : "An Arm or Store",
        "streetAddress" : "124 Main St",
        "addressLocality" : "Beverly Hills",
        "addressRegion" : "California",
        "postalCode" : "90210",
        "addressCountry" : "US"
    }
}}
</script>
```

Here is what GWT sees in the "search appearance > structured data > organization"
[image: Showing no logo, yet showing no errors either. The logo sources are there.]

Upon clicking an entry, we can see that the logo does indeed have a source.
[image: Its own popup as well as the snippet test tool say the logo is good to go]

- Does anyone else see this happening, perhaps with HTTPS src specifically?
- Is GWT not able to use HTTPS for a logo src?
- Is GWT not able to understand CaPs in a URL?
- Is GWT limited to a certain length of URL?
- Is there something wrong with the validator in GWT in general?

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-schemaorg-markup-for-organization.html

Comment: Side note: Again, the schema.org tag should NOT be a synonym for microdata! I am not using microdata yet this is what it tries to force....

Comment: As far as I know GWT does understand logo, can you confirm that GWT is understanding all other schema attributes?

Comment: @bybe Yes it seems to be understanding the other attribs across the board. Im saying "seems" since they are all filled with correct field data within the popup box that appears after clicking a row in the "structured data" view. So it finds the fields (and they validate); perhaps it hints that its just the "table row" reporting view that isn't seeing the logo? -- although we have yet to see it in SERP sidebar alongside the rest of the goodies either (which is expected haha). Its just the GWT rows throwing me off acting like it can't understand/see the logo data that is there.

Comment: Seems odd, on a side note the serp sidebar isn't a sure thing. Its disabled for most niches, and you need good authority, traffic and branding for it to appear on the right side.

Comment: @bybe Amen man, we def got a healthy sidebar going on for various queries, some strange brew of this + googleplus + 3rd party sites. Twas pulling logo from G+ before, but now mostly just shows map. Hence my "hmmm" about this logo thing going on.

Comment: Are your images blocked in robots.txt? Are they on a CDN? Does the GWT account you are in match the version of the site you are on (http/https/www, etc.)?

Comment: @DavidGarcia Yes all is locked and loaded/verified/matches and robots doesn't block images. The src is bypassing the apps compressed/resized image cache store, using origin domain, although, it is normally behind Cloudflare. Turned Cloudflare off 4 days ago due to some instability they had, and it still seems to be doing it even with recently crawled entities.

Comment: quick reminder the email tag should have 'mailto:' included as per example found on https://schema.org/telephone

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue, but when I double checked the guideline.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo

> URL of a logo that is representative of the organization.
>
> Additional image guidelines:
>
> - The image must be 112x112px, at minimum.
> - The image URL must be crawlable and indexable.
> - The image must be in .jpg, .png, or. gif format.

I release my logo is only 225x100, which is a bit shorter than the expected size.

Maybe it's worthwhile to go through each guideline again.