# Product Snippets with JSON-LD + Schema.org - Are there any live examples in Google index?

Tags: search-results, rich-snippets, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

** **EDIT Feb 2016** - Finally JSON-LD seems to be working now in SERPS, with extremely fast changes-to-index time, assuming you have everything with Google merchant center feeds syncd and linked. Make sure the price, stock, and identifier are the same on your JSON-LD as it is on the Google shopping feed. New organization->localbusiness types are live, organization reviews are live... however JSON-LD feed `alt=` endpoints still do not exist, the homepage schema defining custom site name is not active, and G support for schema itemList/dateModified is still questionable. You can still get pagination results and date modified snippets by using literal text strings in your view/template `Showing 1-28 of 8977 Results (321 Pages)`and `Last updated on February 3rd 2016`.

To proceed to a deeper exploration of JSON-LD support, see these:

- [Distinguishing Between Organization and Product Reviews (with Schema.org in JSON-LD)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89845/distinguishing-between-organization-and-product-reviews-with-schema-org-in-json)
- [Why don't search engines support JSON-LD + Schema.org as seperated endpoints via rel=“alternate” or script src?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83372/why-dont-search-engines-support-json-ld-schema-org-as-seperated-endpoints-via)
- [Google Webmaster Tools Not Reporting a Logo from JSON-LD Schema.org [Organization] Markup](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78917/google-webmaster-tools-not-reporting-a-logo-from-json-ld-schema-org-organizatio)
- [How to include your site name in search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89806/how-to-include-your-site-name-in-search-results)

**Original Post Below:**

Google seems to be flip flopping JSON-LD -> Schema.org product [or other types of] snippets. The snippets verify without error in both the testing tool and long term (10+ months) across 5 properties in GWT search console. The snippets have been applied to index, removed, applied, and removed again, seemingly not being applied again in regards to various facets. Since they worked in the past via microdata, and were applied long term, I assume it's due to the switch to JSON-LD.

I have not found any official docs nor examples that say *"Google will support and render products snippets that use JSON-LD*". Same thing with breadcrumb snippets and review looping. All I see is a handful of Google examples for events, movies, recipes, very basic [incomplete] organization etc. This seems strange to me considering the sheer amount of ecom pages using product snippets trumps the amount of movies, recipes, and events combined.

So the question is, **does Google officially support, index, *and* render product markup using JSON-LD?** If so, can anyone point me to a live example to verify this?

** This question is not intended to be "opinion/recommendation based"....im looking for a specific link and subsequent SERP result [evidence] showing that JSON-LD products/etc are indeed rendered within Google.com realm as of late August 2015.

** **EDIT Nov 16 2015** - Another annoying caveat has been found. Google merchant center validates certain shopping feed fields such as condition, stock, and price against live microdata. However, it seems to not recognize JSON-LD.... although, as stated above, it's recommended to use in all the G examples, and it validates the snippet test. So due to this, your merchant center account *could* be suspended because of "differences in presentation data"

Comment: at the moment the JSON-LD I've used does work but the structured data tool does not recognize it

Comment: @Mousey thats interesting...we have the opposite. The snippet test recognizes our LD + Schema.org but it "doesnt work" minus random weeks here and there (which might be Google testing)

Comment: forget to mention mine was embedded in javascript. Some examples are on schema.org for Product -  http://schema.org/Product

Comment: @Mousey do you mean it's just a JSON array between script tags (ie, the LD examples on that page), or are you doing something different? Curious now how you got them to fire live :) Do you have a link or something showing them live and making the SERP widgets?

Comment: it's a javascript that creates the JSON-LD using variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2016:** The documentation got updated and it no longer contains the note. So now JSON-LD seems to be supported for the Products Rich Snippet.

---

Google’s documentation for the [Products Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) says for the [single product page](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products#single_product_page):

> We are in the process of implementing JSON-LD support for this Rich Snippet type. At the current time, we recommend using microdata or RDFa.

So this might explain why it wouldn’t always work, currently.

Comment: Dude thank you, I swear I've looked over that page multiple times and never seen that alert bar!

Comment: Ah i see now, its because they added that alert sometime after June 30th - https://web.archive.org/web/20150630180837/https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products

Comment: @dhaupin Is it that Google is taking plays out of the Microsoft playbook?? Oh! Quick! Sneak it in before we get caught. Maybe no-one will notice and we can point to the page and say see.... we told you! And no I am not a conspiracy theorist- just because Jesse Ventura is my uncle, that has nothing to do with any opinion I might have.

Comment: @closetnoc HAH Ventura. He does have a few good thoughts here and there, kinda. Its like that though i think....hype it up for months just to say, oh wait, you didn't see that tiny alert box that some sympathetic G dev snuck into a buried support doc? Yet they do PSA for derp stuff like "When you go on vacation, don't put noindex on your site". This LD non-support seems more important to PSA, else thousands of sites lose their snippets jumping on the new spec. Mueller, any thoughts on maybe letting people know this stuff en masse (ie webmaster blog)?

Comment: Is there someone at Google who might know about some ETAs?

Comment: I've literally traversed the known internet looking for a oage properly using json ld product snippets. Shame on Google.

Comment: @DavidLerner Amen man. I thought i was crazy for no less than 6 months now. There is some other strangeness too - some massive sites are apparently getting snippets without any markup whatsoever. Do you think Amazon actually uses the "data highlighter" in GWT instead of the Schema.org spec? I think not....yet snippets appear? https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.com%252FDeckmate-Steel-Fire-Bowl-Round%252Fdp%252FB000FI2VFY

Comment: They def need to edit that warning to include more warnings. Example, i edited the question above, using JSON-LD and shopping feeds may cause the feeds/account to be suspended since it cant validate live info is the same. Asking again: Any Google folks out there have insight into this? Timeframes? Something? Just dont be silent!

Comment: Rejoice all ye pro webmasters! Rejoice!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after the latest algo core update it seems lots more JSON-LD schema is functional and sticking in SERPS (knock on wood). Its been sticking for about a week, hopefully it stays for all the OP's of the world to enjoy. Here is an example:

[image]

This is built from the following script template:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "Product",
"name" : "A cleaned title of the item",
"image" : "https://www.example.com/img.jpg",
"description" : "A trimmed and cleaned description.",
"model" : "MODEL-1234",
"itemCondition" : "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
"productID" : "12345678",
"brand" : {
    "@type" : "Brand",
    "name" : "Acme Widget Company"
},
"aggregateRating" : {
    "@type" : "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue" : "5",
    "reviewCount" : "1"
},
"offers" : {
    "@type" : "Offer",
    "priceCurrency" : "USD",
    "price" : "2109",
    "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "seller" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "A Sweet Store"
    }
}}
</script>
```

Also confirmed, Google merchant center shopping feed is [still] able to use the JSON-LD on landing pages for cross-source data validation. I have no way to cite this besides microdata validate/mismatch errors disappearing after supporting more types of product templates with LD. The auto update price seems to work too resulting in a general trifecta of linked data within the G environment.

As a bonus, it also seems they are able to parse reviews better without markup or highlighting (this TPL didn't have schema for reviews until today):

[image]