# Has anyone got product rich snippets to work with ld+json?

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data, json-ld

Has anyone got this to work? Snippets appearing in search results?

Reason I ask is because I've added the script but it's not showing up in Google search results. I added the script last week and Google search console tells me three pages have been processed.

Comment: This is not a forum site but rather a Q&A where people bring descriptions of the problem they are having seeking a solution. In this case, the question will likely be closed. However, if you can re-edit your question with a description of your problem, what you have tried, and one or just a small few specific questions seeking a solution, then your question will not only survive, but you can possible find a solution that works for you.

Comment: @closetnoc I literally asked the same question this morning, seems this is a duplicate - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/84371/38958

Comment: @dhaupin I am not sure if you marked this question as a duplicate, but it seems to be... so I will.

Comment: I'm with closetnoc. Seems like a duplicate because both users are trying to get rich snippets to work

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's a dupe. Don't agree it's a satifying answer however but that's another story.