# How to include your site name in search results

Tags: seo, google, google-search, schema.org, structured-data

I have read the `Include Your Site Name in Search Results` article:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name

..and was wondering if this works? I tried searching Google and I can't find 1 result that has this implemented? Has this been abandoned? Is it only relevant to certain countries?

I spent quite a bit of time browsing the search results from my laptop and couldn't see anything. I went through the search results from my mobile phone and also nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good practice is to put the name, author and url in the code that you are working on.

But to answer your question, I need to link you the news that google putted up before almost a year ago.

**[Google Replaces A Site’s URL In Search Results & Uses Its Site Name & Breadcrumb Path](http://searchengineland.com/google-replaces-a-sites-url-from-the-search-results-uses-their-site-name-breadcrumb-path-219064)**

Comment: But what do you see in the search results? I see the site URL, not the name and breadcrumb path. (?)

Comment: I haven't seen the site name in the search results. I tried mobile as well and nothing. So my question is will Google roll this out or has it been canned? What's the use if it's never going to be used?

Comment: @BrendanVogt Either or is ok, but i suspect they will backtrack because of spammy or keyword injecty abuse of the facet. Its worth the bit of code though regardless...G isnt the only JSON-LD consumer out there, although it is at the forefront of applicable support at the moment.

Comment: @dhaupin You think JSON-LD will be the way of the future to markup structured data?

Comment: @BrendanVogt For sure. Its an efficient way to transport/store "objects", and beyond this Schema.org use, JSON is the standard for a massive amount of the data transport "over the wire" these days. Eventually it will supersede XML, so things like sitemaps, atom/rss, and feeds will go JSON....or at least thats what my crystal ball implies :) XML will never go away as its a low level structure needed for internal things such as module/addon/plugin structs of legacy platforms, but it will indeed be "challenged" by object [JSON] data pipes.